# Minimizing server trips in setting default value in 1:n relationship in lightswitch html5 client

Tags: html, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have lightswitch entities created in the HTML5 client. There is a field that the user should not be setting that needs to be set based on their login. In this case, the client the user is associated with.

The standard examples (in Michael Washington's book Creating HTML 5 Websites ... Using Lightswitch and all over the web) involve assigning the user name as the relevant field, setting up a little handler on the server to return the relevant field using an AJAX call.

This is was all well and good while prototyping, but now that we are doing this for real, there is a relationship to another entity involved, the Client Entity, so you can't just assign the Client Id. So instead of simply assigning a Client ID, now we have associate a whole Client Object to the entity.

[Here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c47c3854-7a9b-4081-8954-14ef9e30bada/setting-default-value-for-a-1n-relation-with-javascript-in-lightswitch-html5-client?forum=lightswitch) the suggestion is to do what ends up looking like this:

```
myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Clients_SingleOrDefault(1).execute().then(function (ClientQuery) {
    entity.setClient(ClientQuery.results[0]);
});
```

My problem is with this part:

```
Clients_SingleOrDefault(1)
```

I need to get that number dynamically, not just a hard coded 1, as that OP suggested. So I can do it in two server calls, one to get the ID, and then the next one to substitute that result into the next call, but that seems ... inefficient.

```
msls.promiseOperation(CallGetClientId).then(function PromiseSuccess(PromiseResult) {
    myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.Clients_SingleOrDefault(Number(PromiseResult)).execute().then(function (ClientQuery) {
        entity.setClient(ClientQuery.results[0]);
    });
});

function CallGetClientId(operation) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        data: {},
        url: '../UserCode/GetClientId.ashx',
        success: operation.code(function AjaxSuccess(AjaxResult) {
            operation.complete(AjaxResult);
        })
    });
}
```

It would seem that there should be a better way to do it. Is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest method of achieving this with one server call is to implement a scalar query.

For example, if you create a scalar query called ClientForCurrentUser against your Clients table you'd be able to make a single client side call as follows:

```
myapp.activeDataWorkspace.ApplicationData.ClientForCurrentUser().execute().then(function (query) {
    if (query && query.results && query.results.length !== 0) {
        entity.setClient(query.results[0]);
    }
});
```

As regards configuring the scalar query, the following post covers an example (note the setting of the 'Number of Results Returned' property):

[Applying where clause to child collection in LightSwitch query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34422695/1301937)

Then, assuming you have a field against your Client record that relates it to the current username (e.g. Client.RelatedUser) you'd implement the following type of PreprocessQuery method against the scalar query:

```
partial void ClientForCurrentUserPersonForCurrentUser_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable<Client> query)
{
    var username = this.Application.User.Name;
    query = query.Where(c => c.RelatedUser.Equals(username, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)).Take(1);
}
```