# Applying where clause to childcollection in LightSwitch query

Tags: linq, lightswitch-2013

How can I have a where clause in a LightSwitch query against a child collection?

In my example, every blog can have many comments and I want to write a query like this so that the admin see only the blog entries without any comments:

```
query = query.Where(q => q.comment.Count() == 0).SingleOrDefault()
```

I've included the SingleOrDefault() because I want the administrator to see only one item per query they can then add a comment and move to next item on the blog screen.

When trying the above query, I get the following compile time error:

Error   2

Cannot convert method group 'SingleOrDefault' to non-delegate type 'System.Linq.IQueryable'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

I thinks this is the right error because:

```
partial void Query1_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable<blog> query)
{
    query=query.Where(q => q.Evaluations.Count() == 0).SingleOrDefault;
}
```

Return IQueryable which is a collection not single one .

I've tried changing the signature to partial void Query1_PreprocessQuery(ref blog query) and now I get another compile error saying blog does not contain a definition for where.

So, how can I implement the required type of query in my LightSwitch HTMLClient app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to organise this type of scalar query, you need to use the following type of LINQ expression in your query's pre-process method:

```
partial void BlogWithNoComment_PreprocessQuery(ref IQueryable<blog> query)
{
    query = query.Where(q => q.comment.Count() == 0).Take(1);
}
```

In addition, you'll need to ensure your query is designed to only return a single result by selecting the 'One' option in the query's 'Number of Results Returned' property as follows (the required property selection is highlighted in red):

[image: Query Designer with Single Result Option]

This type of approach is covered in the following Microsoft blog in the Scalar Queries section:

[Visual Studio LightSwitch Team Blog: How to Create Composed and Scalar Queries (Ravi Eda)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2011/04/18/how-to-create-composed-and-scalar-queries-ravi-eda.aspx)

Even though the screen examples in this blog are based on the Silverlight client, the query techniques it covers apply equally to the HTML client.